# Integrate asp.net authentication with multiple clients' Active Directories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, adfs, asp.net-identity-2

I've done quite a bit of research on Asp.net Identity 2.0 and know that it supports Active Directory authentication but can't figure out how to integrate active directory integration in my particular scenario. The basic premise is that I want the enterprise customers to easily integrate with my website. So when people visit my website (over internet) they should be able to login with their enterprise credentials. Is it possible for me to accept their credentials and authenticate them with their enterprise's AD server? That would be the ideal scenario, or do need to redirect them to their AD server's authentication page?

Comment: Take a look at Active Directory Federation Services - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx.

Comment: @RussCam Thanks. I've actually done a lot of research already and know that I would need to use ADFS. The problem is How would it work with Asp.net so I can authenticate users by accepting their credentials on my website.